# Como capturar a ação de um click em um titulo que está dentro de um container e esse container está dentro de um scrollContainer?

Tags: java, totalcross

Como capturar a ação de um click em um titulo que está dentro de um container e esse container está dentro de um scrollContainer?

```
public void onEvent(Event e) {
            if(e.type == ControlEvent.PRESSED && e.target == ???????){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                   MessageBox mp = new MessageBox("Titulo foi clicado");
                   mp.setBackColor(0xFFFFFF);
                   mp.setForeColor(0X000000);
                   mp.popup();
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E só declarar a variável fora do `initUI(){}` desse jeito ela será vista no código inteiro, e ai você poderá usar ela em qualquer método que criar. Eu queria ver o código inteiro para ajudar mais, mas espero que isso ajude!

```
private ScrollContainer sc;
private Container ct;
private Button tt;

public void initUI(){
    sc = new ScrollContainer(){
        public void initUI(){

            ct = new Container(){
                public void initUI(){
                    setBackColor(0x2196f3);

                    tt = new Button("Titulo");
                    tt.setFont(Font.getFont(true, Font.NORMAL_SIZE + 3).asBold());
                    tt.setBackForeColors(0x757575,0xFFFFFF);
                    tt.setBorder(BORDER_NONE);
                    new MessageBox("Mensagem","Titulo foi clicado").popup();
                    add(tt, LEFT, TOP, FILL,FILL);

                }
            };

            add(ct, LEFT, TOP, FILL, PARENTSIZE+10);
        }
    };

    add(sc,LEFT,TOP,FILL,FILL);

}
public void onEvent(Event e) {
    if(e.type == ControlEvent.PRESSED && e.target == tt){
        System.out.println(e.toString());

        MessageBox mp =  new MessageBox("Mensagem","Titulo foi clicado");
         mp.setBackColor(0xFFFFFF);
         mp.setForeColor(0X000000);
         mp.popup();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa à [resposta do @J. Eric](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340631/64969). Com os meus próprios vícios de desenvolvimento em TotalCross.

Entre coisas que eu codifico, sempre procuro:

- usar os componentes *vanilla* quando não preciso alterar seu comportamento
- usar os `listeners` de eventos para uma programação orientada a eventos
- evitar campos que não são necessários

O que isso significa? Que eu não criaria as classes anônimas para `Container` e `ScrollContainer`, iria manter as instâncias como objetos locais e iria adicionar um `PressListener` no botão:

```
@Override
public void initUI() {
  ScrollContainer sc = new ScrollContainer();
  add(sc, LEFT, TOP, FILL, FILL);

  Container ct = new Container();
  ct.setBackColor(0x2196f3);
  sc.add(ct, LEFT, TOP, FILL, PARENTSIZE+10);

  Button tt = new Button("Titulo");
  tt.setFont(Font.getFont(true, Font.NORMAL_SIZE + 3).asBold());
  tt.setBackForeColors(0x757575,0xFFFFFF);
  tt.setBorder(BORDER_NONE);

  tt.addPressListener(e -> {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    MessageBox mp = new MessageBox("Titulo foi clicado");
    mp.setBackColor(0xFFFFFF);
    mp.setForeColor(0X000000);
    mp.popup();
  });

  ct.add(tt, LEFT, TOP, FILL,FILL);
}
```

Por que faço isso? Bem, o primeiro que não vejo necessidade de se sobrescrever esses métodos. O segundo é porque isso evita o `onEvent`-hell que se tem quando tem muitos componentes na tela, se pode mais facilmente direcionar qual o tipo de evento desejado. Na documentação do TotalCross se diz que usar os `listeners` é pouco eficiente, mas, sinceramente?, estamos lidando com uma ação disparada por um evento de usuário, então se pode ter uma lentidão no tratamento do clique que não será sentida pelo usuário.

Por último, não crio campos desnecessários por estética =)