# Como resolver o problema com a barra superior de um projeto TotalCross

Tags: totalcross

Tenho um Projeto TotalCross e quando eu gero um apk o meu programa fica com o espaço que há abaixo da barra superior do meu dispositivo android e eu gostaria que o projeto ficasse abaixo dessa barra superior

Comment: Tem como postar um print do que está acontecendo? Só através da descrição não consegui visualizar o problema. Se for possível também, tente fazer um código mínimo (de preferência apenas a `MainWindow` e um controle ou outro) que reproduza seu problema. Também é interessante dizer qual a versão do TotalCross sendo usada

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tiver tendo o mesmo problema que eu, consegui achar a solução, e pelo que me informei nas próximas atualizações do TotalCross esse problema será corrigido, para resolver isso basicamente crie esta variável: "private int DPTOP = (int) (Settings.screenDensity*24);" fora dos métodos e quando você for posicionar o contêiner ou algum componente que irá ficar no topo da sua tela, onde você normalmente colocaria TOP, coloque a variável DPTOP, e assim ele ira pular o espaço correto da barra superior do celular.

Comment: Particularmente, achei que a descrição fiou confusa e macarrônica. Você deu uma resposta bem adequada e formatada [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340631/64969). Se conseguir deixar esta resposta tão legível quanto a outra, reverto meu voto nesta resposta